# Moving to next scene in Corona/LUA

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I've been at this for a while now and nothing I try works. I'm trying to make it so when you press the `playButton`, the scene changes to scene2.

Here is the code:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local image, playButton, helpButton, text3, memTimer
print("test")

-- Touch event listener for background image
local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 800  )

        return true
        end
    end


-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )

    local screenGroup = self.view

    image = display.newImage( screenGroup, "openingbackground.png" )
    image.x = _W * 0.5
    image.y = _H * 0.5
    screenGroup:insert( image )

    local playButton = display.newImage( "playbutton.png" )
    playButton.x = _H * 0.33
    playButton.y = _W * 0.90
    playButton.xScale = 0.5
    playButton.yScale = 0.5
    playButton.touch = onSceneTouch
    screenGroup:insert( playButton )


    local helpButton = display.newImage ("helpbutton.png")
    helpButton.x = _H * 0.33
    helpButton.y = _W * 1.1
    helpButton.xScale = 0.5
    helpButton.yScale = 0.5
    screenGroup:insert( helpButton )

    playButton:addEventListener("touch", playButton)


end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )


end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )

    -- remove touch listener for image
    image:removeEventListener( "touch", image )

    -- cancel timer
    timer.cancel( memTimer ); memTimer = nil;

    -- reset label text
    text2.text = "MemUsage: "
end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )

    print( "1: destroyScene event" )
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

The error I am getting is:

`Corona Runtime Error: ?:0? attempt to index a nil value stack traceback: ... Do you want to relaunch the project?`

[image: img]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: can you put a marker at the lines mentioned in error message (like "-- this is line 17" etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
-- Touch event listener for background image
local function playButtonTouched( event )
    storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", {effect = "slideLeft", time = 800}  )
    return true
end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )

    local screenGroup = self.view

    local playButton = display.newImage( "playbutton.png" )
    playButton.x = _H * 0.33
    playButton.y = _W * 0.90
    playButton.xScale = 0.5
    playButton.yScale = 0.5
    screenGroup:insert( playButton )

    playButton:addEventListener("tap", playButtonTouched)

end
```

This is a clean version of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this to your code:

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --

### -- main.lua

---

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )

local scene = storyboard.newScene()
```

-- hide the status bar

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
```

---

### -- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION

-- Touch event listener for background image

```
local function onSceneTouch(event)

if event.phase == "began" then

    if event.target.id == "button1" then

        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 800  )

        return true


    end

end

end
```

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist

```
function scene:createScene( event )

print( "1: createScene event" )

end
```

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:

```
function scene:enterScene( event )

local screenGroup = self.view

local image = display.newImage( screenGroup, "openingbackground.png" )
image.x = _W * 0.5
image.y = _H * 0.5


local playButton = widget.newButton
{
    left = _H * 0.33,
    top = _W * 0.90,
    width = 60,
    height = 10,
    defaultFile = "playbutton.png",
    overFile = "playbutton.png",
    id = "button1",
    emboss = true,
    onEvent = onSceneTouch,

}
screenGroup:insert(playButton)


local helpButton = widget.newButton
{
    left = _H * 0.33,
    top = _W * 1.1,
    width = 60,
    height = 10,
    defaultFile = "helpButton.png",
    overFile = "helpButton.png",
    id = "button1",
    emboss = true,
    onEvent = onSceneTouch,

}
screenGroup:insert(helpButton)

print( "1: enterScene event" )
end
```

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:

```
function scene:exitScene( event )

print( "1: exitScene event" )

end
```

-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)

```
function scene:destroyScene( event )

print( "1: destroyScene event" )
end
```

---

### -- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist

```
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
```

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished

```
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
```

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins

```
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
```

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().

```
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )
```

---

```
return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
playButton = display.newImage( "playbutton.png" )
playButton.x = _H * 0.33
playButton.y = _W * 0.90
playButton.xScale = 0.5
playButton.yScale = 0.5
playButton.touch = onSceneTouch
playButton:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
screenGroup:insert( playButton )
```

Because you are already declaring the playButton as local at the beginning itself , so there s no need to declare as local inside the createScene.